# Reading txt file with more columns than column names in R

Tags: r

I have a txt file with one column that has some + symbols with no column name associated with it. An example is provided below.

```
   Cat    dog        bird
    A       b   +       c
    B       a   +       c
    C       b           d
    B       c   +       a
```

When trying to read this into R, using

```
read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = " ")
```

I get an error that there are more columns than column names. How can I read this file into R, either by removing the column of +'s or by assigning a column name to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `readr::read_fwf` gets the desired output rather intuitively.

```
library(readr)

df <- read_fwf("file", skip = 1)[, c(1, 2, 4)]

colnames(df) <- unlist(read_fwf("file", n_max = 1))[c(1, 2, 4)]

df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Cat   dog   bird 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     b     c    
2 B     a     c    
3 C     b     d    
4 B     c     a
```

with **base R** `read.fwf`

```
df <- data.frame(sapply(read.fwf("file", widths=c(6, 7, 5, 7), skip = 1), 
  trimws))

colnames(df) <- sapply(read.fwf("file", widths=c(6, 7, 5, 7), n = 1), trimws)

df[,c(1, 2, 4)]
  Cat dog bird
1   A   b    c
2   B   a    c
3   C   b    d
4   B   c    a
```